# connect AirPods to MacBook Air (Early 2014) with Sierra - Bluetooth pairing doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, airpods

I followed the steps in [Connect AirPods to MacBook / Macbook Pro with Mac OS Sierra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6oJXGp_gVw) (warning, Youtube video).

[image]

I tried and tried and never see AirPods.

I have a Early 2014 MacBook Air with Sierra. Does this only works with new MacBooks? Is there a technical reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the update macOS Sierra 10.12.4 the connection to AirPods working fine.

In release notes [About the macOS Sierra 10.12.4 Update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207536) nothing about AirPods written.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the AirPod tech specs, either. It just says, "macOS Sierra." Very strange. https://support.apple.com/kb/SP750